# Spree API Authentication extension not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

I'm working on an extension to authenticate users over the Spree API. I have search a lot but almost no information exits on this topic, and the few extensions I have found doesn't work.

I created a extension based on the ones I have found and I'm getting the following error:

AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'sign_in' could not be found for Spree::UsersController)

```
module Spree
  module Api

      #class UsersController < Spree::Api::V1::UsersController 
      Spree::Api::V1::UsersController.class_eval do
        before_action :authenticate_user, :except => [:sign_up, :sign_in]

        def sign_up

          @user = Spree::User.find_by_email(params[:user][:email])

          if @user.present?
            render "spree/api/users/user_exists", :status => 401 and return
          end

          @user = Spree::User.new(user_params)
          if !@user.save
            unauthorized
            return
          end
          @user.generate_spree_api_key!
        end

        def sign_in
          puts("hola controller")
          @user = Spree::User.find_by_email(params[:user][:email])
          if !@user.present? || !@user.valid_password?(params[:user][:password])
            unauthorized
            return
          end
          @user.generate_spree_api_key! if @user.spree_api_key.blank?
        end


        def user_params
          params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
        end


    #end
    end
  end
end
```

My routes.rb

```
Spree::Core::Engine.add_routes do
  # Add your extension routes here
  namespace :api, defaults: {format: 'json'} do
    resource :users do
        #resource :v1 do
        member do
          #post :sign_up
          post :sign_in
        end
    #end
    end
  end
end
```

Can you please help me figuring out what am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the routes in v1 namespace in `config/routes.rb`:

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    resource :users do
      member do
        post :sign_in
      end
    end
  end
end
```